# Prove that if x,y > 0 then (1/2)(x+y) ≥ √(xy). For which x,y does equality hold?

Tags: proof-explanation

Answer:
x+y ≥ 2√(xy) ⇔ (x+y)^2 ≥ 4xy ⇔ x^2+y^2+2xy ≥ 4xy ⇔ (x−y)^2 ≥ 0, which is true. Equality holds when x=y.

I've solved it until (x−y)^2 ≥ 0, but I don't understand "which is true".
If y is larger than x won't it not be true? e.g. 14 - 16 = -2. (I get this now!)

Also, it means x is larger than or equal to y.
How do we know equality holds when x=y and not when x is larger than y? (Still don't get this)

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it not true that $(x-y)^{2} \geq 0$?

Comment: $(-2)^2=4 \ge 0$

Comment: If y is larger than x won't it now be true? Oh but is that not important because we're already assuming it is true?

Comment: ohhhh..... Then how do we know equality doesn't hold when x is larger than y?

Comment: Notice $x+y = 2\sqrt{xy} \Leftrightarrow (x+y)^2 = 4xy \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2+2xy = 4xy \Leftrightarrow (x−y)^2 = 0$

Comment: But the question says the equation is larger than or equal to root xy not just equal to root xy...

Comment: Why won't the answer be 'equality holds for x is larger than or equal to y'? Instead the answer says equality holds only when x=y... why is this?

Comment: Yes but equality hods if and only if $(x-y)^2=0$

Comment: Ohhhh if its less than or more than then is that inequality? oh.... omg yeah 'equality' Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the forest for the trees.

It doesn't matter if $x \ge y$ or $y\ge x$ because $(x-y)^2$ is a square.  And if $x \ne y$ then $(x-y)^2 = (y-x)^2 > 0$.  And $(x-y)^2  = 0 \iff x-y = 0 \iff x=y$.

There are only three options.

1. $x > y$.  Then $x-y > 0$. And $(x-y)^2 > 0$.  For example.  If $x = 16$ and $y=14$ then $x+y= 30$ and $2\sqrt{xy} = 2\sqrt{14*16} = 8\sqrt {14} < 30$.   And $(x-y)^2 = (16-14)^2 = 2^2 = 4 > 0$.
2. $x = y$.  Then $x-y = 0$.  And $(x-y)^2 = 0$.  For example.  If $x = 16$ and $y=16$ then $x+y = 32$ and $2\sqrt{16*16}=2\sqrt{256}=2*16 = 32$.  And $(x-y)^2 = (16-16)^2 = 0^2 = 0$.

and

3. $x < y$ then $x-y < 0$ and $(x-y)^2 > 0$.  For example.  If $x = 14$ and $y-16$ then $x+y = 30$ and $2\sqrt{xy} = 2\sqrt{16*14} = 8\sqrt{14} < 30$.  And $(x-y) = (14-16)^2 = (-2)^2 = 4 > 0$.